# User Rights letters to numbers

Tags: chmod

I am having Problems converting user rights. I want to assign the following rights to certain files/folders but dont know hat to translate them into a format which chmod will work with like `chmod 755`.

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

will be?

And

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

will be?

And finally

```
-rw-r--r--
```

will be?

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39710/how-to-get-permission-number-by-string-rw-r-r/39745#39745, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9509/is-there-a-web-based-converter-between-rwx-and-the-octal-version?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short version:

- Permissions can include: read(r), write(w), execute(x)
- Therefore, permissions are expressed in a row of three characters, for example rwx (to give all permissions)
- When a permission is denied, a "-" is placed, for example: `r--` to give only read permission.
- because there are three types of users, we will need 3 x 3 characters:

  ```
   owner | owner group | others
  ```

for example `rwx` `rwx` `rwx` gives all types of users all permissions.

- these permissions can be expressed in octal numbering, where:

  ```
   read    =  4
   write   =  2
   execute =  1

   so: 
   r-- = 4
   rw- = 6
   rwx = 7
  ```
- example:

  ```
   rw- r-- r--
  ```

gives everyone read permission, only user can write. In octal:

```
    644
```

(4+2+0 | 4+0+0 | 4+0+0 )

Your example:

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

is probably the output of `ls -l`, where the preceding `-` means it is a file. In your second example:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

the item is a directory (`d`)

---

#### About the `s` flag

From [the Wikipedia article on setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid):

> setuid and setgid (short for "set user ID upon execution" and "set
> group ID upon execution", respectively) are Unix access rights flags
> that allow users to run an executable with the permissions of the
> executable's owner or group respectively and to change behaviour in
> directories. They are often used to allow users on a computer system
> to run programs with temporarily elevated privileges in order to
> perform a specific task.

An example is `passwd` (`-rwsr-xr-x`) which can change write-protected files on behalf of a user.

A pretty good description is to be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on Wikipedia.

#### The `t` flag (sticky bit)

(Again) from [the Wikipedia article on Sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit):

> When a directory's sticky bit is set, the filesystem treats the files
> in such directories in a special way so only the file's owner, the
> directory's owner, or root user can rename or delete the file. Without
> the sticky bit set, any user with write and execute permissions for
> the directory can rename or delete contained files, regardless of the
> file's owner.

On Linux systems, the `t` flag is ignored when used on files.

Numerically, the sticky bit, the setuid bit and setgid bit are set using the first digit of a 4-digit octal value. From [`man 1 chmod`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/chmod.1):

> A numeric mode is from one to four octal digits (0-7), derived by
> adding up the bits  with values  4,  2,  and  1.   Omitted digits are
> assumed to be leading zeros.  The first digit selects the set user ID
> (4) and set group ID (2) and restricted  deletion  or  sticky  (1)
> attributes.   The  second  digit  selects permissions for the user who
> owns the file: read (4), write (2), and execute (1); the third selects
> permissions  for  other  users  in  the file's  group,  with  the
> same  values;  and the fourth for other users not in the file's group,
> with the same values.

So:

- `rwsr-xr-x` would be `4755`, using the conversion for `rwxr-xr-x` to get `755` we saw earlier, and `4` for the setuid bit as mentioned here.
- `rwxrwsrwt` would be `3777`, using the conversion for `rwxr-xr-x` to get `777`, and the leading `3` from the setgid bit (`2`) and sticky bit (`1`).

Comment: +1. Add a comment about the fact that the `d` is not a permission flag  (and maybe a link to the "s" and "t" flags for the experts) and it will be perfect!

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for the explanition finally understood that system, just one more thingwhen i use chmod 755 on a folder it should be (d)rwxr-xr-x but it refuse and still is (d)rwxr-sr-x. What is the -s- part?

Comment: @Shaeldon updated my answer

Comment: @JacobVlijm one correction: Linux does not respect the setuid bit on directories, only setgid is considered.

Comment: @muru but isn't that what it sais already?

Comment: @JacobVlijm To me, it reads: "the owner and/or group of any files put into the directory are set to the owner/group of the directory." Maybe caching at work.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I was checking the wrong section ;).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert them to numbers. `chmod` understands symbols just fine, if you split them into user, group and other fields. The following are equivalent:

```
chmod 755 
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

So given a set of permissions like, split them like so:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  == - rwx rwx rwx
drwxr-xr-x  == d rwx r-x r-x
-rw-r--r--  == - rw- r-- r--
```

And then assign the first triplet to `u`, the second to `g` and the third to `o`, skipping the hyphens:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
chmod u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

When two fields are the same, you can combine them. The last `chmod` would be the same as:

```
chmod u=rw,go=r
```

And you can use `a` (all) to assign to `u`,`g` and `o` at once, so the first is equivalent to:

```
chmod a=rwx
```

Now, there are a few special permission bits: `s` ([setuid/setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)) and `t` ([sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)).

These are shown over the field where `x` is normally seen, so if a directory has the sticky bit for others, you'd see a `t` (if execute permissions are present) or a `T` (if execute permissions are not present) . For example, the permissions of `/tmp`:

```
drwxrwxrwt
```

In such cases, you need to write `t` as `xt`, and `s` as `rwxs`:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwxt
```

- The setuid bit means that when this file is executed, it runs as the user who owns the file, not as the user executing it. Consider `passwd` (used for changing the password):

  ```
  # stat `which passwd`
  Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
  ```

  If I (user `muru`) run `passwd`, the process that is started runs with `root`'s permissions, not with mine. It is usually seen on binaries which need to be root for performing some action (`passwd` edits `/etc/shadow`, for example).
- The setgid bit on a directory means that any newly created files or directories in it inherit the group ownership. It is usually seen on directories used for web or FTP servers, etc.
- The sticky bit means that even if an user has write permissions on the directory, they cannot move or rename another user's files. It is usually seen on shared directories, like `/tmp`.