# Why do mount, ping and su have a sticky bit set?

Tags: permissions, executable

In `/bin` most binaries don't have a sticky bit set except for: `fusermout`, `mount`, `umount`, `ping`, `ping6` and `su`.

Why are these ones not supposed to be deleted or renamed? Is it because they are used in certain critical scripts and if so, does that mean all other binaries aren't vital and the system could work without them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the sticky bit, that's the setuid bit. A sticky bit usually applies to directories, you can see that in `/tmp` for example:

```
$ stat -c '%A %n' /tmp /bin/ping /usr/bin/crontab 
drwxrwxrwt /tmp
-rwsr-xr-x /bin/ping
-rwxr-sr-x /usr/bin/crontab
```

The `t` indicates a sticky bit, an `s` in user modes indicate setuid and an `s` in group modes indicate setgid.

The setuid bit makes the command be run as *the user who owns the file*, usually `root`. This is done because:

- `ping` and `ping6` need root access to use raw sockets. See [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/a/1035983/334516) and [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/51874/70524). As the SU answer notes, some distros now use capabilities instead of setuid — my Arch Linux system doesn't have setuid on `ping`.
- `su` needs root access to switch to an arbitrary user
- `mount` (and `umount`, etc.) need setuid to mount things that are specified as being mountable by anybody (via `users` option in `/etc/fstab`) (see [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107500/why-does-mount-have-the-suid-bit-set))
- `crontab` is setgid, since the crontab files are stored in a location only writable by root and the `crontab` group:

  ```
  $ stat -c '%A' /var/spool/cron/crontabs
  drwx-wx--T
  ```

  (note: the crontab directory is also sticky.)

Also see:

- [What is the first number for in a 4-number chmod argument (such as `chmod 4555`)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/581290/158442)

Comment: A long time ago, sticky bits usually applied to (executable program image) files, not to directories.  In contrast, a Debian 8 and a FreeBSD 10 system that are conveniently to hand have zero files with the sticky bit set.

Comment: @JdeBP what did a sticky bit applied to an executable do? Was it like setuid then?

Comment: No.  Surprisingly, this is barely covered anywhere on Unix and Linux.  There really should be a question and answer.

Comment: [Now there is.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293149/)